# I can't convert HTML to PDF with jsPDF

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, jspdf

I'm trying to use jsPDF but isn't works, I don't know what is wrong.

In my  I've this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsPDF/jspdf.js"></script>
```

My JS code is:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function generaPDF(){
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        var specialElementHandlers = {
            '#ejemplo':function(element,renderer){
                return true;
            }
        };
        var html = $("#ejemplo").html();
        doc.fromHTML(html,200,200,{
           'width':500,
           'elementHandlers':specialElementHandlers
        });
        doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');
    }
</script>
```

And my HTML code is:

```
<table align='center' class='tablatitular' id='ejemplo'>
<tr><td>Dat1</td></tr>
<tr><td>dat2</td></tr>
</table>
<div onclick='javascript: generaPDF();'>To PDF</div>
```

If I try this, I've the error:

doc.fromHTML is not a function doc.fromHTML(html,200,200,{....

What can be the problem?

Comment: Can you console.log(doc)?

Comment: I found the problem: I need some JavaScript libraries more....but How can respect the styles or add styles to the pdf results?